# iGraph installation on Mac: cairo dependency

Tags: python, igraph, cairo

I am using Mac. I installed igraph in Python with `pip install igraph` and it was working well, except for plotting the graphs.

I searched online and I installed cairo with `brew install cairo`. Ever since, I am getting the following error anytime I simply import igraph:

```
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': dlopen(libcairo.so.2, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/lib/libcairo.so.2' (no such file)
```

and the error message continues with several folders where it tried to look for cairo.

It seems the installation of cairo was not successful. So I tried install cairo using `pip install pycairo`, but I cannot install it:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycairo which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: Can you try `pip install cairocffi` instead? I've been using igraph with Cairo and `cairocffi` on my Mac with Homebrew and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I tried, but no luck yet... Now I have installed cairo, cairocffi and igraph

Comment: You are installing libraries through three different systems: `pip`, conda and Homebrew. Try not to mix them too much, or conflicts like this can easily arise. If you are using conda anyway, then install _everything_ using conda, i.e. both `python-igraph` and `cairocffi`.  Test with a _clean_ conda environment. Generally, when something like this happens, it's always a good idea to start with a clean environment.